# Unable to export valid jar file?

Tags: java, class, jar, export

[image]

In my project i have five classes but when i export jar file of project it only include some of classes and not all of the classes which are in the source folder.
how can i fix this?

As Jar does not include all classes i end-up with **NoClassDefFoundError**.

1)for my project i am using eclipse version 3.6.2,ADT version 20, and latest Android SDK

2)all classes are under SRC folder

Comment: exporting .jar from my project by project->export->jar file

Comment: Is the resources folder under the src folder?

Comment: Eclipse? Netbeans? IntelliJ? BlueJ? Command line? It'd make sense to tell people what you're actually using.

Comment: @ftom2:no, resource is separate folder

Comment: @Dave:sorry for my less information about problem,please check my update.

Comment: if ur desired class is not displayed , expand the jar by clicking on it and see whether your class is there in the jar or not
and after that check it u have any other jar having the same class , in case of conflict usually this problem occurs

Comment: @Hussain:i have already extract the jar each time when i export but it dont show the desired .class file though it shows the java file for the same .

Comment: if it is not showing the desired class then there is no point of using the jar file , remove it and download a new jar

Comment: for more confusion , take screen shots of your expanded jar file , class and build path screen view , then we may hep better

Comment: @dd619 - let me understand, you have some classes sitting under src, and others under Resources folder (why would you have classes there)? When you export a jar it only includes the classes that are under src.

Comment: @ftom2:no, all my java file are in SRC folder only .

Comment: I guess some classes just didn't compile. Check project's `classes` folder.

Comment: @Vadzim:i checked the classes folder and it includes all the classes.

Comment: What are those exclamation marks near problematic classes on the picture?

Comment: @Vadzim:its just warnings(some variables are declared but never used);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out.

In eclipse when you export the jar file it includes only the classes which don't have any errors or warnings.So, to generate jar file with all the classes including warnings you need to select **generate Jar with warnings.**